# Create file with filesystem C++ library

Tags: c++, filesystems

How to create a file with filesystem C++ library?

I know there are different ways to create a file but I am perticularily intrested with filesystem library.

Comment: Which filesystem library? Do you mean the standard file streams, or something else? What have you tried so far?

Comment: C++ `filesystem` library. I didn't find anything here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs

Comment: The library you've linked to is for manipulating existing files, and for traversing filesystems. To create a file, you can simply open it for writing, using the standard file streams (`std::ofstream`, for instance).

Comment: You create a file with `ofstream` class. C++17's filesystem address something different....

Comment: When you say filesystem I'm not one hundred percent certain what you're referring to could you be a little more specific. If you're referring to basic file manipulation than fstream is the way to go, if you only want to create files than ofstream. If you're talking about creating directories then you're out of luck because there isn't a way to do so... Unless you want to use system specific headers such as windows.h and the CreateDirectory function. Check out boost it makes life much easier http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 20):

This code will create a folder and a txt file (+ adds some text into there)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path path{ "C:\\TestingFolder" }; //creates TestingFolder object on C:
    path /= "my new file.txt"; //put something into there
    std::filesystem::create_directories(path.parent_path()); //add directories based on the object path (without this line it will not work)

    std::ofstream ofs(path);
    ofs << "this is some text in the new file\n"; 
    ofs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This uses `std::ofstream` to create a file. `std::filesystem::path` here is used only to retrieve the path but not to create the file.

Answer (score 16):

You can't create a file using [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) (C++14) or [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (C++17). The library can manipulate the path (including the name) and the status (permission) of existing, [regular files](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file), but is not intended for manipulating their contents.

Though [`resize_file()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file) can manipulate file contents by truncating or zero-fill, it does only work with files that are already existing. When passing a non-existing file as parameter `p`, it throws `resize_file(p, n): invalid arguments: operation not permitted`.

Comment: I like when an answer just answers the question, but fills in nuances so it is clear in what way the function is not supported. I used this to confirm my findings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't

With filesystem you can operate on directories.
It is possible to delete exact file, but not to create.
In case of any updates in the topic I will update my answer :)